# Get all options of custom attribute in magento 2 .phtml file

Tags: magento2, frontend, customer-account, custom-attributes

I want to get all options of my custom attribute in frontend customer register.phtml and edit.phtml file.

In CE

Comment: Are you using EE or CE?

Comment: I'm using Magento 2.0.5 CE.